# linq if statement problem

Tags: c#, linq

```
public IEnumerable<string> References { get; private set; }

References = hrefs.
                Select(href => href.Attributes["href"].Value).
                Distinct().
                ToArray();
```

I'm trying to make it behave so that if href.Attributes["onclick"] exists then I will add onclick value to References otherwise href value. How can I check this inside linq? now I always add href value.

EDIT:

and how if class exist go to next element and don't add anything. i forget about this.

Comment: Are the hrefs coming from HtmlAgilityPack or XmlReader? The type of checking you have to do depends on that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe...

```
References = href
                .Select(href => 
                   href.Attributes["onclick"] != null ? 
                      href.Attributes["onclick"].Value
                    : href.Attributes["href"].Value)
                .Distinct().
                .ToArray();
```

**Edit:**

To answer the question update, just add

```
.Where(href => href.Attributes["class"] == null)
```

before the `Select` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the hrefs are of type `HtmlNode` from the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - please verify in your question.

Edited to add checking for `class` attribute:

```
References = hrefs
                .Where( href => href.Attributes["class"]==null)
                .Select(href => (href.Attributes["onlick"]!=null) 
                  ? href.Attributes["onlick"].Value
                  : href.Attributes["href"].Value)
                .Distinct()
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Why need to filter those `href.Attributes["class"]==null`?

Comment: @TheSmartest: That's how I interpreted the posters addition to the question: *and how if class exist go to next element and don't add anything.* Since it's somewhat vague I might be totally off though.